# Proof of transformation formula

Tags: probability-theory

There is a short proof of a transformation formula in my probability lecture notes. It states that for a continuous random variable $X$, if $Y=h(X)$ is increasing over the set $\{x:f_X(x)>0\}$, then 
$$f_Y(y) = f_X(h^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|$$
for $y$ such that $f_X(h^{-1}(y))>0$. And the proof goes
$$
F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)\\=P(h(X)\leq y)\\=P(X\leq h^{-1}(y))\\=F_X(h^{-1}(y))\\=f_X(h^{-1}(y))\frac{dh^{-1}(y)}{dy}
$$

I don't understand the last step. Although I know that it probably follows from the chain rule, I do need a detailed clarification on how the last step is obtained. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the last step follows from the chain rule.

However, I think that the last equality is misleading, since it claims that

$F_X(h^{-1}(y)) = f_X(h^{-1}(y))\frac{d}{dy}h^{-1}(y)$.

In the proof (ignoring the last step), it is shown that $F_Y(y) = F_X(h^{-1}(y))$ (both LHS and RHS are functions of $y$.)

Therefore, differentiating both sides wrt. $y$, the LHS is

$\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = f_Y(y)$,

since derivative of cdf $F_Y(y)$ is pdf $f_Y(y)$.

For the RHS, the derivative is

$\frac{d}{dy}F_X(h^{-1}(y)) = f_X(h^{-1}(y))\frac{d}{dy}h^{-1}(y)$,

where the chain rule was used.

So we can conclude that

$f_Y(y)=f_X(h^{-1}(y))\frac{d}{dy}h^{-1}(y)$

Comment: Crystal clear. Many thanks!